# How do I format error logs with Winston in Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, winston

I have a Node.js app that it using [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) for logging. I am printing my logs using [printf](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#formats) like this:

```
winston.createLogger({
  level: 'debug',
  format: winston.format.combine(            
    winston.format.timestamp({ format: 'HH:mm:ss.SSSSS'}),
    winston.format.printf(log => `[${log.level}] [${log.timestamp}] ${log.message} `)
  ),
  transports: []
});
```

This works fine except in the case of "error" logs. When a log has a log level of 'error', the log writes an entry that's formatted like this: `[${log.level}] [${log.timestamp}] ${log.message}${error.message}`. Notice, there is no space between the log message and the error message.

How do I put a space between the log message and an error message if the log level is an error?

Comment: In that code you don't have `error.message` anywhere, can you show how are you calling `logger.error`, you don't even have a transport. Please show the actual code so we can help you.

Comment: would be very aprreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of the [documentation](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#creating-your-own-logger) winton only supports that `format` parameter for `info` logging.

[image]

Comment: While this is true, you can still write your own `format` function. I will add answer below.

Answer (score 0):

While this is true that, by default `winston` only support formatting only for level `info`. However you can write your own `format` function. See the example below.

```js
const { combine, timestamp, label, printf } = winston.format;

const myFormat = printf(info => {
    // This will customize the Error Message
    if(info instanceof Error) {
        return `${info.timestamp} [${info.label}] ${info.level}: ${info.message} ${info.stack}`;
    }
    return `${info.timestamp} [${info.label}] ${info.level}: ${info.message}`;
});

winston.createLogger({
    level: "info",
    format: combine(
        winston.format.splat(),
        label({ label: filename}),
        timestamp(),
        myFormat,
    ),
    transports: [
      new winston.transports.File({ filename: path.join(os.tmpdir(), "test", "test.log"), level: "info" }),
    ],
});
```